java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient]
Trying to upgrade Spring Boot 3.0.0 to 3.3.0, I get this error when using mvn spring-boot:run :
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcClient]
Here's my pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SuperHeroes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SuperHeroes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <start-class>com.example.hero.SuperHeroesApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
             <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SWAGGER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Metrics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for completion in application.properties -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.hero.ExampleSuperHeroesApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/testresults</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/cobertura</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                    <!-- Turn off if no xref report -->
                    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <targetJdk>${java.version}</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-changes-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.1</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>jira-report</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>


Also, here's my application.properties :
###
#   Database Settings
###
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/superheroes
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:initdb.sql
###
#   Hibernate Settings
###
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

Tried changing the JPA version in pom.xml but didn't help.

Remove the <dependencyManagement> section from the end of your pom. It's clashing with the dependency management that you're inheriting from spring-boot-starter-parent. This clash is resulting in an unwanted mixture of versions which makes JdbcClient unavailable.
